# ZAP Spider scan displays 0% status and terminates in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

I am new to ZAP OWASP. I have created a ZAP Jenkins job.
I am getting below Message with Form login authentication

```
7983 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Starting spidering scan on Context: SecurityTest at Mon Oct 05 10:06:27 EDT 2020
7989 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN STATUS [ 0% ]
[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]

8023 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
8023 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Scan will be performed from the point of view of User: fred
8044 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: USer
8274 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...
8278 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete: true
```

Spider Scanning status is showing only 0% and shows Spider scanning complete: true.
It is not displaying a 100% completion and report is not displayed with expected result.
How to fix this issue?

```
    USER user IS NOW ENABLED

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ATTACK MODE(S) INITIATED

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN ENABLED [ TRUE ]

    SPIDER SCAN SETTINGS
        AUTHENTICATED SPIDER SCAN [ TRUE ]
        RECURSE: [ TRUE ]
        SUB TREE ONLY: [ FALSE ]
        MAX CHILDREN: [ 0 ]
        CONTEXT ID: [ 1 ]
        USER ID: [ 0 ]
        USER NAME: [ user ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN THE SITE [ https://localhost:8080/webui ] AS USER [ User ]

7983 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Starting spidering scan on Context: SecurityTest at Mon Oct 05 10:06:27 EDT 2020
7989 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spider initializing...

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SPIDER SCAN STATUS [ 0% ]
[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]

8023 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Starting spider...
8023 [ZAP-SpiderInitThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Scan will be performed from the point of view of User: fred
8044 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-1] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.users.User  - Authenticating user: user
8274 [ZAP-SpiderThreadPool-0-thread-2] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.spider.Spider  - Spidering process is complete. Shutting down...
8278 [ZAP-SpiderShutdownThread-0] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.extension.spider.SpiderThread  - Spider scanning complete: true

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] AJAX SPIDER ENABLED [ FALSE ]
    SKIP AXAJ SPIDER FOR THE SITE [ https://localhost:8080/webui ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] ACTIVE SCAN ENABLED [ FALSE ]
    SKIP ACTIVE SCAN FOR THE SITE [ https://localhost:8080/webui ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] CLEAR WORKSPACE OF PREVIOUS REPORT(S) [ FALSE ]
    SKIP CLEARING WORKSPACE

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] GENERATE REPORT(S) [ TRUE ]
    [ XML ] SAVED TO [ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JENKINS_ZAP_VULNERABILITY_REPORT_34.xml ]
    [ HTML ] SAVED TO [ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\JENKINS_ZAP_VULNERABILITY_REPORT_34.html ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] CREATE JIRA ISSUES [ FALSE ]
    SKIP CREATING JIRA ISSUES

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SUMMARY...
    ALERTS COUNT [ 0 ]
    MESSAGES COUNT [ 5 ]

[ZAP Jenkins Plugin] SHUTDOWN [ START ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont try to debug authentication problems with ZAP on Jenkins unless there are no other alternatives. Do that using the ZAP desktop - that way you can see whats going on. Authentication is hard - see the ADDO Workshop videos on https://www.alldaydevops.com/zap-in-ten I go into a lot of detail on them.

Comment: Authentication is successful. But scan shows 0% status. i have added more log in the above problem statement.

Comment: How do you know authentication is successful? The message `Authenticating user: user` just tells you that ZAP is trying to authenticate, not that it suceeded. In any case, you might have configured ZAP incorrectly and even though it appears to ZAP that it has authenticated in reality it has not.

The fact that the spider exists so quickly implies to me that it is not successfully authenticating. Try with the ZAP desktop and examine the requests and responses.

Comment: In ZAP Desktop i am able to run and spider scan gets completed with all the results. Tried with form based authentication.

Comment: Thats a good start. Now try it using the same configurations that you're using in Jenkins.

Comment: it is the same configurations i am trying and it is not working

Comment: I am facing the same pb. desktop work good but python not

Comment: Best option - ask for more help on the ZAP User Group: https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users - trying to diagnose complex issues via stackoverflow is a complete pain ;)
But do be aware that the ZAP Jenkins plugin is no longer officially supported.